# Is there a hotkey for making a face from the inner outline I did in this picture?

Tags: modeling, faces

I am trying to make the darkened section of the reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all inner edges (like on screenshot), then go to **Mesh** - **Faces** - **Fill** (**Alt+F**), it will fill all with *Triangles*, selecting all of them. To turn *Most* of them into *Quads*, go to **Mesh** - **Faces** - **Tris To Quads** (**Alt+J**). 
If there's any *Triangles* left - dissolve their edges, and then just continue the needed loopcuts through created faces, where needed (mostly at the place, where *Triangle*'s edges were dissolved) with **Knife** tool (**K**).

I'm pretty shure that there's a better method, but this will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a face with Make Face (<kbd>f</kbd>), or Fill (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>), or Grid Fill - see the Faces menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>), but I don't see how this would help you in this particular situation as the middle part seems to be a separate object in your reference image. You should model it as such.